# Copy filtered rows with specific column without headers to new sheet after existing rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a source excel data with 'n' number of columns which contains repeated group of data in groups of 'x' number of columns. I would like to copy first group with header, non empty and specific columns to existing different sheet. For rest of the groups, i would like to filter and copy only data into existing sheet after last row.

I have spent sufficient amount of time looking for unified solution but no luck yet. I consider myself a novice in this area.

```
'current property 1: Copy with headers
wsRawData.ShowAllData
FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Current Record Type 1 (50)", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

With wsRawData
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows("1:" & .Rows.Count)).AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A:A,I:K,C:F,Y:AB,AJ:AJ").Copy

        With wsCurrentProperty.Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

End With'this block works just fine

'current property 2: copy only data
wsRawData.ShowAllData
FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Current Record Type 2 (50)", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

Dim TotalRange As Range

With wsRawData
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows("1:" & .Rows.Count)).AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A:A,I:K,C:F,AR:AU,BC:BC").Copy ' i need a offset of one row here

        'below logic works just fine and copies beyond existing rows
        Last_Row = wsCurrentProperty.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'MsgBox Last_Row

        With wsCurrentProperty.Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

End With
```

As of now first section to filter, copy selected columns with headers to new sheet is working, but second part of copy only data from second group is not working.

Comment: Would just filtering for the 2, pasting, then sorting not do this?

Comment: Well ideally i wanted filtering, specific column selection and header removal during data sourcing rather than in pasted sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i was able to get an answer. Here is the updated code for second block which needed correction:

```
wsRawData.ShowAllData
FilterRow = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Current Record Type 2 (50)", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

With wsRawData

    Intersect(.UsedRange, .Rows("1:" & .Rows.Count)).AutoFilter Field:=FilterRow, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A1:A" & wsRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count & ",I1:K" & wsRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count & ",C1:F" & _
            wsRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count & ",AR1:AU" & wsRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count & ",BC1:BC" & wsRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Copy 

        Last_Row = wsCurrentProperty.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        wsCurrentProperty.Activate

        wsCurrentProperty.Cells(Last_Row + 1, 1).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete' this line deletes header being copied over instead of using offset

End With
```